# Post-action in a jenkins github-organization-pipeline-build with the scripted syntax

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins is configured a build for all the repo of my GitHub Organization.

I use this syntax in my Jenkins file:

```groovy
 node {
   stage('build') {
     checkout scm
     mvn clean install
     ...
   }
 }
```

At the end, some status is automatically updated to my pull-request

I want to do some stuff AFTER the pull-request update, how do I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in your pipeline with the base plugin because it happens post-run completion based on the run result. You would most likely have to build a plugin that does something like this.